# Java JPMS and jars with included libraries

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-platform-module-system

If I create a custom JRE with all required modules, do I still need to package my `Spring Boot` application
with dependent jars for that application to work?

Comment: Wouldn't the custom JRE include all the jars required to execute your application treated as modules?

Comment: I have no clue, to be honest, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: So, do I need only a skinny jar?